# how to download mails attachment using IMAP and php

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments

I am using this code for download attachments from gmail

```
    $savedir = __DIR__ . '/imap-dump/';

    $inbox = new IMAPMailbox($hostname, $username, $password);
    $emails = $inbox->search('ALL');
    if ($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        foreach ($email->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
            $savepath = $savedir . $attachment->getFilename();
            file_put_contents($savepath, $attachment);
        }
       }
   }
```

but when we execute it shows this error Cannot connect to Gmail:

```
Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection refused
```

How can i solve this problem?`

Answer (score 0):

Verify the connection in your IMAPMailbox Class. The code you have posted is procedural code and does not handle connections. Please edit your OP and add the IMAPMailbox Class.

Answer (score 0):

So you SSL Libraries installed port 993 is a secure port.

Check IMAP configs ref a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

First check your class. The connection to google's imap server should be like "imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl".
Also, you have to disable protection against low secure apps in your google account settings. that's the only way. after that, save, log out from all your google connections.
then, https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
again, log into your google account.
now it should log your app to the gmail